# Find repositories with no protected branches on GitHub with Python

Tags: python, github, python-3.6, github-api, github-enterprise

I have an instance of GitHub Enterprise and I am trying to do an audit of my Organization within GHE of repositories which have no protected branches. I am able to find which repository branches are protected or not using PyGitHub. But I am trying to figure out Python logic which would only give me repositories which do not have any protected branches. GitHub's API only provides branches which are protected.

**Here's my code so far:**

```
from github import Github
g = Github(access_token, base_url='<github-enterprise-url>/api/v3')
for repo in g.get_organization('orgName').get_repos():
    for branch in repo.get_branches():
        b = repo.get_branch(branch.name)
        u = g.get_user()
        if b.protected:
            print("Repo is --> ",repo.name, "| Repo ID is ", repo.id ,"| Branch --> ", b.name, " (protected)")
        else:
            print("Repo is --> ",repo.name, "| Repo ID is ", repo.id ,"| Branch --> ", b.name, " (not protected)")
```

**Output I get is:**

```
Repo is -->  puppet | Repo ID is  2 | Branch -->  dev  (protected)
Repo is -->  puppet | Repo ID is  2 | Branch -->  master  (not protected)
Repo is -->  java | Repo ID is  3 | Branch -->  master  (not protected)
Repo is -->  foobar| Repo ID is  7 | Branch -->  master  (not protected)
Repo is -->  afu.github.io | Repo ID is  8 | Branch -->  master  (protected)
```

How would I use Python to only give me the repos with no unprotected branches in the logic?

Comment: Aggregate your data, and filter by desired condition.